# thread detach - закрывается окно

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Вопрос странный конечно, но почему-то закрывается окно, созданное с detach после закрытия приложения которое его создало. Что-то с сигналами?

Код запуска:

```
std::thread thw
{
    [=]()
    {
        // создание нового окна
    }
};
if (thw.joinable())
    thw.detach();
```

Comment: А как вы закрываете приложение?

Comment: Кнопкой закрыть :) крестиком в простанародье

Comment: А на чем этот крестик? На терминале, который открывается вместе с приложением, или на окне, которое вы сами создали?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, на терминале, но это большой разницы кажется не имеет, если приложение заканчивается само, то картина та-же, созданные detach окна закрываются. Сам тест, который запускает окна - это консольное приложение.

Comment: Почитал, похоже все потоки прерываются, когда закрывается создавший их процесс ([What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744617/2752075)), и, видимо, выход из main или нажатие крестика на терминале завершают весь процесс, а не основной поток.

Comment: Эмм.. с pthread (linux) на C такой беды нету, но там надо с сигналами играться, чтоб main не ждал.. А пути решения есть какие нибудь?

Comment: Формально в WinAPI все потоки равноправны, но в стандартной библиотеке это не так, и при завершении основного потока вызывается `ExitProcess`. Это насколько я помню, на 100% поручиться не могу, специально этим вопросом не интересовался.

Comment: Можно в конце `main` сделать join вместо detach. Или, если неудобно, можно при завершении потока устанавливать какой-нибудь флажок, а в конце `main` ждать установки этого флажка, и только потом выходить. А защититься от закрытия терминала - видимо никак.

Comment: Спасибо, надо наверное реализовать какой то список тредов, и в конце действительно интересоваться как оно там.. и после этого выходить. Хотя конечно ситуация забавная, и заменой на CreateProccess тут не обойтись..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, оформите как правильный ответ пожалуйста.

Comment: `thread.detach()` в коде практически всегда является грубой ошибкой, как и наличие в программе живых порожденных потоков при выходе из main

Comment: С тредами толком не работал, так что нормальный ответ с примером кода вряд ли сделаю. Лучше сами напиши́те, когда разберетесь с созданием списка тредов.

Comment: Да остановитесь на том как есть, что все закрывается и баста :) это правильный ответ. Остальное велосипеды, как я понял под winapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Завершение функции `main()` является завершением программы [согласно стандарту](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#5). Поэтому неважно, Windows это или OS/2 — detached поток не влияет на время жизни программы. Такие потоки как раз и создаются тогда, когда совершенно не важно завершится поток или нет — есть либо какие-то методы опроса таких потоков, либо же их уничтожение в середине работы не имеет значения (хотя это выглядит просто плохим дизайном). В подавляющем большинстве ситуаций, отсутствие `join` на созданном потоке, это просто ошибка.

Comment: Ключевое слово тут не `detached поток не влияет на время жизни программы` а `detached поток работает только во время жизни программы`

Comment: @NewView, это одно и то же. Потоки не живут вне процессов, а отсоединённый поток не может заставить процесс жить, следовательно, при окончании работы «основного потока», отсоединённый поток умирает.